# Projections.rowCount does not return unique result

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection, rowcount

I have following code. I need to calculate the total number of rows returned by this criteria. I have a number of predicates which I have implemented as restrictions. I have used Projection list with group property and row count with criteria but it doesn't return a unique result. What am I missing:

```
public Integer getSurveyCount(
        Date from,
        Date to,
        Integer districtId,
        Integer tehsilId,
        Integer qanungoiHalqaId,
        Integer patwarCircleId,
        Integer mauzaId,
        Integer surveyorId,
        Integer surveyTypeId,
        Integer verified) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Survey.class);

    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("surveyId"));

    if (from != null && to != null) 
        criteria.add(Restrictions.between("surveyDatetime", from, to));
    else if (from != null && to == null)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("surveyDatetime", from));
    else if (from == null && to != null)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("surveyDatetime", to));

    if (verified == 1)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("verified", true));
    if (verified == 2)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("verified", false));

    if (surveyTypeId != null && surveyTypeId != 0) 
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("surveyType.surveyTypeId", surveyTypeId ));

    if (surveyorId != null && surveyorId != 0){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("surveyor.surveyorId", surveyorId));
    }

    if
    (mauzaId != null && mauzaId != 0)
        criteria.createCriteria("location")
                .createCriteria("mauza")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("mauzaId", mauzaId));
    else if 
    (patwarCircleId != null && patwarCircleId != 0)
        criteria.createCriteria("location")
        .createCriteria("mauza")
        .createCriteria("patwarCircle")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("patwarCircleId", patwarCircleId));
    else if
    (qanungoiHalqaId != null && qanungoiHalqaId != 0)
        criteria.createCriteria("location")
        .createCriteria("mauza")
        .createCriteria("patwarCircle")
        .createCriteria("qanungoiHalqa")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("qanungoiHalqaId", qanungoiHalqaId));
    else if
    (tehsilId != null && tehsilId !=0)
        criteria.createCriteria("location")
        .createCriteria("mauza")
        .createCriteria("patwarCircle")
        .createCriteria("qanungoiHalqa")
        .createCriteria("tehsil")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("tehsilId", tehsilId));
    else if
    (districtId != null && districtId != 0)
        criteria.createCriteria("location")
                .createCriteria("mauza")
                .createCriteria("patwarCircle")
                .createCriteria("qanungoiHalqa")
                .createCriteria("tehsil")
                .createCriteria("district")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("districtId", districtId));


    criteria.setProjection(
            Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("surveyId"))
            .add(Projections.rowCount()));

    return (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: If you want a single result, why do you have a groupProperty projection? This returns the number of rows for each surveyId, and it's not what you want, right?

Comment: it gives this error if not used : ERROR: ERROR: column "this_.survey_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 58

Comment: Also remove the orderBy:you can't sort a rowCount by surveyId. The post the generated SQL query, and the complete stack trace of the exception.